# Use R to acquire Q1 temp data from individual month files containing daily data (336 files total)

Tags: r, loops, mean, file-manipulation

I wish to calculate the mean temperature data for 1 km grid cells from a list of csv files containing 1 km grid cell max and min daily values for individual months.

Here are the numbers of files I am dealing with and their approximate data. A problem is that the first two columns contain coordinate data which shouldn't be averaged. Another problem may be that January, February and March contain have differing numbers of days and so will have different numbers of columns.

Here are the numbers of files I am dealing with and a rough overview of my approach to achieving the desired result:
[image: Here are the numbers of files I am dealing with and a rough overview of my approach to achieving the desired result]

Here is an example of a data file:
[image: Here is an example of a data file]

I have already tried to import multiple files using the list.files() function but think I require some guidance on breaking down the stages of the above.

I could do this by hand but it would take a few days, and I wouldn't learn anything.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When I think about for loops I generally think how would 1 iteration go from start to end. From your list of files (list.files), with your caution on differing lengths of days, I'd process jan(s) list.files()[seq(1, 336, 3)] separate from feb(s) list.files()[seq(2,336,3)], then realize, oh, jan[min], jan[max], what order are list.files() in, can I seq that? So maybe its base 6 so jan_min is seq(1, 336, 6) and jan_max is seq(4, 336, 6) assumes for a year c(jmin,fmin,mmin,jmax,fmax,mmax).Likely helps to dput(head(1janmin)), dput(head(1janmax)) above as data.

Comment: Thanks, Chris, I have so far got to the point of automating the averaging of each file individually, and have just achieved extraction of those columns into a single df. I am having some trouble using the spread function on 11 million row df, which seems to take >10 mins without finishing processing. Thanks for your help.